# Check if powershell script is loaded - environment file

Tags: powershell

I've got several powershell scripts that are loading environment.ps1 file.

Now I've created a "install.ps1" where I "link" in those powerhshell script that I need. How can I check if the environment.ps1 file are already loaded or not?

```
###############################################################################
# INSTALL SCRIPT  
###############################################################################

function LoadFiles
{
param([string]$fileName = "unknown.ps1")

Try
{
     . .\$fileName
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Host "Problems accessing "+$fileName +" file, check the file location" -ForegroundColor Red
    Break
}
}


LoadFiles "Environment.ps1"             #environment.ps1, variables, Add-    PSSnapin
LoadFiles "MySiteWebApp.ps1"            #this file also loads environemnt
LoadFiles "CreateCTHUB.ps1"             #this file also loads environment
```

Comment: What are you loading in those other scripts? Functions? Environment variables? You can check for the presence of functions and things like that.

Comment: In my environment file I'm having alot of ex Write-Host "$hostname" ... When I run my install script that include alot of smaller scripts I then get alot of "garbage" ..

Comment: Show, don't tell. How are you loading `environment.ps1`, what is the current result, and what should the result actually look like?

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a variable in your environment.ps1 (for example $EnvVarsImported) and set its value to $true? Then you can assume that all the functions and vars from that script have been imported when you successfully check for the existence of that variable in the importing script (install.ps1).